# Integrating $e^{p(x)}$ with $p$ an arbitrary polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Are there any non-linear real polynomials $p(x)$ such that $e^{p(x)}$ has a closed form antiderivative? If not, is the value of $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{p(x)}dx$ known for any $p$ with negative leading term other than $-x$ and $-x^2$?

Comment: Ok, now a little more serious approach. Have you heard of the Chain rule? Because this poses a problem if you want anti derivatives in terms of elementary functions if p(x) is a polynomial with degree more than 1. This answers your first part of the question.

Comment: Yes the "exponential family" is well known to be nice to integrate.

Comment: Really? Because I know that $e^{-x^2}$ does not have a closed form antiderivative in terms of standard functions. I'm looking for exact answers here, not approximations to an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in addition to the usual $e^x$, $e^{x^2}$ and $e^{(x+a)^2}$ you can find an explicit formula for perfect cubes:

$$\int e^{(x+a)^3}\ \text{d} = - \frac{(a+x)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3},\ -(a+x)^3\right)}{3(-(a+x)^3)^{1/3}}$$

And generally for perfect $n$-th powers:

$$\int e^{(x+a)^n}\ \text{d}x = -\frac{(a+x) \left(-(a+x)^n\right)^{-1/n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},-(a+x)^n\right)}{n}$$

Finally, there are incomplete powers like:

$$\int e^{x^n + a}\ \text{d}x = -\frac{e^a x \left(-x^n\right)^{-1/n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right)}{n}$$

The problem is that if you just step a bit away from the perfect powers, you will have very hard times in evaluating other integrals. For example when you have to integrate the function

$$e^{x^n + x + a}$$

You find that it's analytically unsolvable.

Comment: Well those formulas contain a function (the [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html)) that basically are just *defined* as being the the integral on the left hand side so it's not really a closed form antiderivative. However these formulas can be useful analytically and numerically if the software one is using comes with these functions built in.

Comment: @Winther I guess the OP just wanted to see those integrals because they can be solved in terms of special functions. Thing that you cannot do with the example at the end of my answer (and you need, in that case, extrema to get a numerical answer. (Unless one finds a way to express the solution in powers series)).

Answer (score 1):

There is a well known method to integrate functions of the form

$$\int_a^b e^{\ \lambda\ F(x)}\ \text{d}x$$

And it's called LAPLACE'S METHOD.

What you need is to assume the function $F(x)$ have a unique global maximum at $x = x_0$. So the value of $F(x_0)$ will be the largest between all the other values of $F(x)$.

The factor $\lambda$ is usually a large number that provides the integral to be treated in a way in which the maximum contribution is indeed the one due to the function calculated in the maximum point, and this is why we take the Taylor series for $F(x)$:

$$F(x) = F(x_0) + F'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac{1}{2}F''(x_0)(x - x_0)^2 + R$$

Where

$$R = O((x-x_0)^3)$$

Since $x_0$ is a max, $F' = 0$ in that point and you end up only with the first and third term. Hence the integral is now

$$\int_a^b e^{\ \lambda\ F(x)}\ \text{d}x \approx e^{\lambda F(x_0)}\int_a^b e^{-\ \lambda \frac{1}{2}|F''(x_0)|(x-x_0)^2}$$

Which is a gaussian integral and you end up with the Laplace Method for integrals:

$$\int_a^b e^{\ \lambda\ F(x)}\ \text{d}x \approx \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda|F''(x_0)|}}e^{\ \lambda\ F(x_0)}$$

as $\lambda\to \infty$.

Other cases shall be treated one by one.

**More here**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any examples $p(x)$ with a closed form antiderivative in terms of "standard" functions, though?

Comment: @Vik78 Mmm... Do you have some particular $p(x)$ in mind (like polynomials or trigonometric...) or you mean in general?

Comment: I'm asking about polynomials, as I said in the top post.

Comment: @Vik78 Well, in addition to the usual $e^x$, $e^{x^2}$ and $e^{(x+a)^2}$ you can find an explicit formula for perfect cubes:

$$\int e^{(x+a)^3}\ \text{d} = - \frac{(a+x)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3},\ -(a+x)^3\right)}{3(-(a+x)^3)^{1/3}}$$

And generally for perfect $n$-th powers:

$$\int e^{(x+a)^n}\ \text{d}x = -\frac{(a+x) \left(-(a+x)^n\right)^{-1/n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},-(a+x)^n\right)}{n}$$

Finally, there are incomplete powers like:

$$\int e^{x^n + a}\ \text{d}x = -\frac{e^a x \left(-x^n\right)^{-1/n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right)}{n}$$

Comment: @Vik78 There is not much more. For example the integral of the function

$$e^{x^n + x + a}$$

Is analytically unsolvable.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: I will add this as another answer, to make it clear for everybody! Thank you!

Comment: @EnricoM. May I know how to handle the case $x_0$ is one of the end points? In this case, $F'(x_0)$ may not be zero, so the factor will depend on $F'(x_0)$, right?